# arabic localize event module in Dotnetnuke

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I installed DNN event modules, and its working perfect, but the problem is that I need to localize the module to be viewed in English on the English site and in Arabic on the Arabic site. Is there any way to do this? Or is there any way to show a column in English and hide the Arabic column and vs.?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNN modules support localization. I am not sure if there is an Arabic language pack for the Events module, but you can create your own using the tools in DNN

These videos may be of some use for you

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/Community/Learn/Video-Library/View-Video/Video/232/View/Details/Introduction-to-the-DotNetNuke-Language-Module

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/Community/Learn/Video-Library/View-Video/Video/234/View/Details/Installing-Language-Packs-in-DotNetNuke